# pass a variable through several web pages simultaneously

Tags: php, variables, href, html

I have a variable that needs to be passed through several php pages. The following code works fine when I send the variable to 1 page(index.php)

```
echo "<a href='index.php?PHOTO=".$i."'>select</a>";
```

But how can I send a variable to several web pages (like index.php  and test.php) using one line of code?

My programming code is in a way that this should happen only in one href code, so I need the above code to be extended in a way that supports sending variable to several web pages.

thanks in advance

Comment: Have you considered using a Session?

Answer (score 1):

`$_SESSION['my_var']= $var` and pass it where ever you want

Comment: I have two cookies in 2 different web pages, that their values is set based on the value of the variable in href command: So I think session can't be used here.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you need sessions. They are a way of keeping variables for an user in the server. In php, a common way of doing it is:

```
session_start();
$_SESSION['name'] = 'john doe';
```

and then, on subsequent page requests:

```
session_start();
$name = $_SESSION['name'];
```

Session should be started once per request, if session is needed. More detailed information on: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-start.php